# Why is crossed this webkit css instruction

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, web-frontend

When I'm opening Chrome developer tools I have something I cannot explain.
I have always thought that a css property  is crossed because overweritten in an other class.

But I have this situation :

[image: crossed -webkit instruction]

This is the hierarchical top so I don't get why it is crossed. If syntax error it should have a warning sign next to it.
Does someone can explain me why it is crossed like this?

Comment: if it's the latest chrome, It'll be looking for the unprefixed version see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Comment: If you go to the next tab "computed" you can see where the override is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property property is crossed just because your version of Chrome doesn't need the `webkit` prefix. Just simple like that :)